# How to make graphical objects be static during re-sizing?

Tags: java, swing, layout, awt

Below I have attached the code, that draws a simple vertical line at the centre of the window, but when I resize the window, the line leans towards the resizing direction.

But when try with two lines, the 1st line leans while the second remain fixed.

I want them to be fixed irrespective of the given size.

```
public class finalPlot{

    static JFrame f = new JFrame();

    public static void main(final String[] args){
        f.setTitle("Plot");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // f.setSize(500,500);
        f.setResizable(true);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(final WindowEvent e){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        f.add(new PlotArray(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.pack();
        f.show();
    }
}




class PlotArray extends Canvas{

    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        return new Dimension(500, 500);
    }

    public void paint(final Graphics g){

        final Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        final Dimension size = getSize();
        final Line2D lin =
            new Line2D.Float((float) size.width / 2, 90, 250, 250);
        final Line2D lin2 = new Line2D.Float(45, 300, 250, 150);
        g2.setPaint(Color.blue);
        g2.draw(lin);
        g2.draw(lin2);

    }

}
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then don't use  `size.width / 2` because it's widht of your Canvas component. Use a static number instead.

Comment: size.width/2 was the issue... Thank You

Answer (score 0):

`PlotArray.paint` is called every time the window is resized, and each time that happens, `lin` is drawn with a different x value because the `PlotArray` has a different width. To keep it constant, you can store its width in an instance variable the first time `paint` is called.